# How do I label my BarLegend?

Tags: plotting, legending

How do I add a label to my `BarLegend`? I would like to add the label "Depth" to the right of my `BarLegend`.

```
BarLegend[{GrayLevel, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Use the option `LegendLabel` to `BarLegend`. See [its documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendLabel.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
Row[{BarLegend[{GrayLevel, {0, 1}}], 
  Rotate[Style["   Depth", 14], 90 Degree]}]
```

[image]

??

Comment: Seems to do the job!

Answer (score 3):

Based on @MarcoB comment:

```
BarLegend[{GrayLevel, {0, 1}}, LegendLabel -> Placed[Rotate["Depth", -Pi/2], Right]]
```

[image]